# Why unobtrusive validation wont work in asp.net mvc3 without using @Html.BeginForm()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

To make unobtrusive validation work in asp.net mvc3 you have to use the html helper `@Html.BeginForm()` as mentioned in this very good post : http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html.

Without using the helper unobtrusive validation will not be triggered. I could verify that.

Can you explain me what does the helper `@Html.BeginForm()` do to allow unobtrusive validation to be triggered when the form is submitted ?

Can you also explain me how could I do that manually (read allow unobtrusive validation without calling the `@Html.BeginForm()`) ?

Please note that I know I can call unobtrusive validation using `$("#myform").valid()` but I would like to know the magic behind the helper and how to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `BeginForm` (see http://j.mp/WrmAyk for the `FormExtensionsclass`), a new `MvcForm` object is created.

If you look in the constructor of this class (see http://j.mp/Wrml6F for the MvcForm class) you will see that it creates a new `FormContext` object: `_viewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();`.

When an input, textarea or select is rendered using the HTML helper, the following is called: `tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlHelper.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(name, metadata));`, which takes care of rendering the validation attributes from the model metadata.

This `GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes` method (see http://j.mp/Wrn4oa for the HtmlHelper class) checks to see if the FormContext is null before rendering attributes:

```
FormContext formContext = ViewContext.GetFormContextForClientValidation();
if (formContext == null)
{
    return results;
}
```

This is why no validation attributes are rendered unless you are within a form. You can get round this by creating a 'fake' `FormContext`, like @karaxuna suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Write this in your view and it will work:

```
 ViewContext.FormContext = ViewContext.FormContext ?? new FormContext();
```

When code is inside @Html.Beginform (in the same view), then html element validation attributes are got from metadata, In other case, it is not.